# AutoComplete need to get value as well

Tags: angularjs

I am using this angular plugin

https://github.com/JustGoscha/allmighty-autocomplete which is working fine

I am showing country list over autosuggestions using http method

```
function getMyHttpData(){
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  $http.jsonp(request).success(function(data){
    // the promise gets resolved with the data from HTTP
    deferred.resolve(data);
  });
  // return the promise
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

But when i submit the form it is taking country name. i want to take it id only

any idea

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the plugin documentation,there seems to be a property like this

**on-select : (optional) Pass a function that will receive changes, when a suggestion is selected. It passes the full string of the suggestion.**

You could write a function which retrieves the id of the country from your array based on the suggestion and return that instead.So the ngmodel would be set as the id

Comment: Could you please provide example for that